# Data model testing with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, junit, datamodel

In my project i have a lot of hbm.xml files from which i generate the java classes and the sql for the db. Semantic errors within the hbm.xml files are shown to me after calling buildSessionFactory() which is really annoying for the current situation. I would like to have a test class which does that for me with a slightly different config(use ebedded derby instead). My current "solution" looks like that:

```
    String dbName = "test";

    try{
        SessionFactory fact = new Configuration().configure()
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true")
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","")
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","")
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect")
                                                 .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create-drop")
                                                 .buildSessionFactory();
        assertNotNull(fact);

        Session s = fact.openSession();
        assertNotNull(s);

        s.close();
        fact.close();
    }catch(Throwable t){
        fail(t.getMessage());
    }
```

But this it not really satisfying from my point of view.
I would also like to check if the named queries and so on are all ok. Is there a way to do that kind of tests in an automated process?

The second part of my question then is, if derby is a good choice for testing, why can't i automatically delete the db after the test ended? I'd like to specify a parameter in the url like

```
    "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true;drop=true"
```

By using this solution i end up with a dir named like the variable dbName and a derby file in my project directory which is not cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your named queries, a solution could be to call them in the test with bogus arguments (the queries would probably return nothing, but at least it would force hibernate to check them) ; something along the lines of :

```
 s.getNamedQuery("Whatever").setParameters(...).execute/query
```

Now is your problem the fact that you cannot easily get the names of all queries ?

As for the derby db, can't you just "manually" get rid of the created folder at the end of your test (in the tearDown, for example ?)

It seems like the location of where the derby base is created can be controled with a java property :

http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/develop/develop14.html

http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/develop/develop12.html#HDRSII-DEVELOP-13018

Comment: I looked through the API but i can't find a method which would give me back all named queries or so. So this still remains a problem. To delete the derby db I would have to know the path to the directory, how is it determined?

Comment: The location of the folder seems to be editable ; I edited my answer with some links. As for getting the list of named query, I don't know ..

Comment: Thanks i just realized that i can already implement this, i already use the java_temp_dir ^^. But the testing of the named queries still remains :(